# Sums in statistical mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I am evaluating the partition function of a system of particles and incurred in sums like
$$
S(a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^\frac{\kappa}{2}e^{-(2k+1)a}
$$
being $\kappa\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=m_0\beta$ a physical parameter. As usual, $\beta=1/k_BT$. In the low-temperature limit, $a\gg 1$, we are in the lucky situation where the exponential goes rapidly to zero increasing the value of $k$. So, few terms of the series are a good approximation anyway. My question is: Are there techniques to evaluate such sums in closed form as happens for even $\kappa$?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $k$ in the exponential?  Or should it be $n$?

Comment: It should be $k$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a similar sum in Wolfram Alpha (Mathematica) and found:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^m (2 k + 1)^{\kappa/2} e^{-(2 k + 1) a} 
= 2^{\kappa/2} e^{-3 a} \left(e^{2 a} \Phi(e^{-2 a}, -{\kappa/2}, 1/2) - e^{-2 a m} \Phi(e^{-2 a}, -{\kappa/2}, m + 3/2)\right)\;,
$$
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent. The sum is said to converge for $e^{Re(a)}$ > 1.

Taking the limit as $m \to \infty$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2 k + 1)^{\kappa/2} e^{-(2 k + 1) a} = 2^{\kappa/2} e^{-a} \Phi(e^{-2 a}, -{\kappa/2}, 1/2) 
$$

This seems to be reasonable in the large $a$ limit since
$$
\Phi(e^{-2a},-\kappa/2,1/2) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-2a\ell}}{(1/2 + \ell)^{-\kappa/2}}
$$
and the overall result in that large $a$ limit is just:
$$
e^{-a}
$$
as might be expected by looking at the $k=0$ term in the sum.

---

Edit:

It's actually even more straightforward...

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2 k + 1)^{\kappa/2} e^{-(2 k + 1) a} 
=2^{\kappa/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k + 1/2)^{\kappa/2} e^{-(2 k + 1) a} 
$$
$$
=2^{\kappa/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-a}}{(k+1/2)^{-\kappa/2}}e^{-2 k a}
$$
$$
=2^{\kappa/2}e^{-a}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(e^{-2 a})^k}{(k+1/2)^{-\kappa/2}}
$$
$$
=2^{\kappa/2}e^{-a}\Phi(e^{-2a}, -\kappa/2, 1/2)\;,
$$
where the last step just identifies the sum with the well-known (or maybe not so well known) Lerch transcendent .

Comment: Thank you. It is a smart trick to limit the sum to $m$ and then take the limit to $\infty$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can come in handy sometimes :)

Comment: Actually, I'm just now seeing, that you can use the definition of the Lerch transcendent to algebraically rewrite the sum... So, it's really just trading a sum for a better know transcendental function...

Comment: You are right. The point now is: Why does Mathematica get stuck on this sum even if I specify $\kappa$? From these results it seems straightforward.

Comment: Heh. Maybe Mathematica isn't so smart after all. OTOH it might be assuming all the other variables are general complex numbers and being careful about convergence.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the second term in the sum is independent of $n$ you can bring it in front. The difficult part of your expression you want to calculate is then

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)^{\kappa/2}$$

This can be expressed in terms of the [Riemann zeta function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%282j%2B1%29%5E%28a%2F2%29+from+j+%3D+0+to+infinity) modulo some normalization.

Comment: I suspect that the formula contains a typo, and that the $k$ in the exponential should be an $n$.  But the OP has not confirmed this.

Comment: The OP has now confirmed this.